# Hotkey to change keyboard layout to Dvorak doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I assigned a hotkey to change my keyboard layout to Dvorak:
<kbd>Start</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Time & Language</kbd> > <kbd>Region & Language</kbd> > <kbd>Additional date, time and regional settings</kbd>  > <kbd>Change input method</kbd> > <kbd>Advanced settings</kbd> > <kbd>Change language bar hot keys</kbd> > <kbd>To English (United States) - United States-Dvorak</kbd> > <kbd>Change Key Sequence</kbd>

But it doesn't work. I tried all the different modifiers (**Ctrl**, **Ctrl+Shift**, and **Left Alt+Shift**) with every number.
Only the default layouts like **English (United States)** can be assigned to a hotkey.

My Google-fu didn't find me anyone with the same issue. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Since my PC's last Windows update, I find *all* user-set keyboard shortcuts fail, though that may not be related to your issue. You could try a third-party keyboard shortcut manager, such as Clavier+, to launch a .bat file that switches the layout. Good luck getting Dvořák to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue when I switched from Win7 to Win10.
The following method worked for me:
Under <kbd>Advanced keyboard settings</kbd>, I chose <kbd>English (United States) - United States-Dvorak</kbd> in <kbd>Override for default input method</kbd>

Comment: The OP was specifically asking for keyboard shortcuts. Perhaps I am missing something but your answer appears to refer to menus?

Comment: After you set your keyboard shortcuts, some of the layouts does not work (specifically dvorak). when overriding default input method makes the shortcuts work for me.